# Questions about Maxwell capacitance matrix and reference point selection

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, capacitance, conductors

Let's consider a system of n conductors. If I'm not mistaken, the Maxwell capacitance matrix tells us that the following system of equations applies:
\begin{align} 
Q_1  &= C_{11}V_1 + C_{12}V_{12} + \dots + C_{1n}V_{1n}  \\ &\;\;\vdots \notag \\ Q_n  &= C_{1n}V_{n1} + C_{2n}V_{n2} + \dots + C_{nn}V_{n}
\end{align} where $C_{ii}$ represents self capacitance of i-th conductor, $C_{ij}$ represents capacitance between i-th and j-th conductor, $V_{i}$ represents voltage between i-th conductor and reference point in infinity and $V_{ij}$ represents voltage between i-th and j-th  conductor.
If we now "move" each diagonal element of our system and we define $Q_{i}'$ as $Q_{i}' = Q_{i} - C_{ii}V_{i} $ we get the following equations:
\begin{align} 
Q_1'  &=  C_{12}V_{12}+ C_{13}V_{13} + \dots + C_{1n}V_{1n}  \\ &\;\;\vdots \notag \\ Q_n'  &= C_{1n}V_{n1} + C_{2n}V_{n2} + \dots + C_{n-1n}V_{nn-1}    
\end{align}
If we now select an arbitrary reference point R then : $V_{ij} = V_{iR} - V_{jR}$ . If we now return to our system then:
\begin{align} 
Q_1'  &=  C_{12}(V_{1R} - V_{2R})+ C_{13}(V_{1R} - V_{3R}) + \dots + C_{1n}(V_{1R} - V_{nR})  \\ &\;\;\vdots \notag \\ Q_n'  &= C_{1n}(V_{nR} - V_{1R}) + C_{2n}(V_{nR} - V_{2R}) + \dots + C_{n-1n}(V_{nR} - V_{n-1R})   
\end{align}  which means:
\begin{align} 
Q_1'  &=  (C_{12} + \dots + C_{1n})V_{1R} - C_{12}V_{2R} - \dots - C_{1n}V_{nR} \\ &\;\;\vdots \notag \\ Q_n'  &= -C_{1n}V_{1R} - C_{2n}V_{2R} - \dots + (C_{1n}+\dots +C_{n-1n})V_{nR}
\end{align}
Which means that:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
Q_1' \\
\vdots \\
Q_n'
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{11} & \dots & b_{1n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
b_{1n} & \dots & b_{nn}
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
V_{1R} \\
\vdots \\
V_{nR}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where
\begin{align}
b_{ii} &= C_{1i} + \dots + C_{ni} \\
b_{ij} &= -C_{ij} \\ 
\end{align}
and :
\begin{align}
B_{NxN} = \begin{bmatrix}
b_{11} & \dots & b_{1n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
b_{1n} & \dots & b_{nn}
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{align}
Finally we get the following equation:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{11} & \dots & b_{1n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
b_{1n} & \dots & b_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
Q_1' \\
\vdots \\
Q_n'
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
V_{1R} \\
\vdots \\
V_{nR}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now it seems to me that the left side of equation is independant of the selection of reference point R. Which , if true, I guess would mean that the right side of equation is same however we pick the point R,which, I guess, would mean that the voltage between i-th capacitator and any point R is same , which , obviously, doesn't seem to be true. Did I make an error? How can I interpret this result?

Comment: The rank of the capacitance matrix is (n-1), i.e. the "raw" capacitance matrix is singular (See [here](http://www.av8n.com/physics/capacitance.htm).).  I think this property may be the cause of the trouble, but I have not verified it.

Comment: side note: general properties of the capacitance matrix were systematically (and rigorously) treated in a recent paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.10251

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@HEMMI's comment already contained the essence of the answer.

Small caveat, you are mixing up the Maxwell capacitance matrix and the mutual capacitance matrix. Your matrix $B$ is what is usually called the Maxwell capacitance matrix, and $C$ is the mutual capacitance matrix.

You error is in the inversion of $B$. You cannot do that since $B$ is singular. You can see that the line of constant vectors, ie $\mathbb R (1, ..., 1)$ is in its kernel, which translates the independence of the reference point. This is why if you want to solve the equation, $Q = BV$, the solutions are always given up to a an additive constant vector.

Note that conversely, for a solution to exist, $Q$ must be constrained. In fact, it is easy to see that the constraint is precisely the conservation of total charge $Q_1+...+Q_n$ which can be checked from direct calculations, or by noting that you have capacitor network which is closed so charge stays within.

In fact, you can prove that the rank of $B$ is $n-1$, which shows that the additional constant vector is the only ambiguity and the net neutral charge is the only constraint.

Hope this helps.

**Answer to comment**

Yes, your previous problem assumes you have a ground. You were implicitly saying that $C_{ii} = 0$, and when it isn't zero, you are effectively connecting the $i$th conductor to the ground via a capacitor. Note that now charge can leak into the ground, you do not have the constraint of conserved charge and $C$ will not be singular in general, you'll now be able to invert it.

You might be worried as this brings us back to the original problem, since charge is affected by a constant shift of voltage. However, in this case, the voltages are unambiguously defined as differences with respect to the ground, so you should not expect such an invariance. You can retrieve the invariance by explicitly adding the ground. Mathematically, you are adding an extra line and column to $C$ to add the ground, and modifying accordingly the matrix. However, it isn't more practical, and having an invertible $C$ is pretty handy.

Let's look at an example of this. In practices, your conductors are bounded, then there is a natural reference point which is infinity, taken as the ground. Take for example a conducting ball (1) of radius $a$ contained in a conducting, cocentric, spherical shell (2) of inner radius $b$ and outer radius $c$ with $a<b<c$. You can calculate:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
Q_1 \\
Q_2
\end{pmatrix}
 = 4\pi\epsilon_0\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{ab}{b-a}  & -\frac{ab}{b-a}\\
-\frac{ab}{b-a} & \frac{ab}{b-a}+c
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
V_1 \\
V_2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
As you can see, only the shell has a self-capacitance, making $C$ invertible. Thus $V$ cannot give the same $Q$ by shifting its origin. The absence of $C_{11}$ is precisely due to shileding. In general, it can be identified by block structure of $C$.

Note that it isn't trivial to prove that the capacity matrix of $n$ conductors can be obtained by mapping it to an effective capacitor network. This is possible iff $C$ is a diagonally dominant matrix with negative off diagonal entries and positive diagonal entries. It would be surprising if this were always the case in electrostatics.

Comment: A bonus question if I may. At the electromagnetics course I attend the elements Cii (self-capacitance) are mentioned in the context of an infinite 
conducting plane. Is the original system of equations in my question based on the assumption that n conductors are in the presence of an infinite 
conducting plane? Meaning would there be "self-capacitance  addents" in the mix if n conductors were to exist by themselves?